# Should we consider the addEvenetListener method a loop?

Tags: javascript, loops

As far as I understand, the `addEvenetListener` method will usually just listen to a certain event and when that event is triggered a callback function will be called to perform everything in the event handler code in that callback function.

`addEventListener` listens **for each** triggering of a certain event. To me it seems quite like a for each loop as initiated by the `forEach()` method.

I assume we could at least say both `forEach()` and `addEvenetListener` are loopish functions, though just functions (methods).

Comment: "*Should we consider the addEvenetListener method a loop?"* Absolutely not. The function itself doesn't listen to events. It gets called only when you call it. The callback passed to it is (potentially) called repeatedly, but there is no such thing as a "loopish function". It's an event listener, plain and simple. That term already implies that it is called whenever the event happens. You could consider it to be an *observer* or *subscriber*, if you like these terms better.

Comment: @FelixKling - I think OP means that the listener itself is a "loop" in the meaning of listening continuously in the background for the event to occur, in the way it is structured in the underlying `C` language.

Comment: @vsync: But that's not correct either. The part that is listening is something internal to the browser. That part simply calls handler. Consider `for(...) { foo(); }`. Would you say `foo()` is a "loop" only because it is called inside a loop?

Comment: @FelixKling - OP probably knows it's internal to the browser, that is obvious it is internal, but the question is how does a listener work behind the scenes. Maybe it is some sort of interval checking all the time? Do you know how it really listens? (i'm talking `C` implementation here)

Comment: @vsync: It doesn't really matter how it is implemented internally. An event handler or subscriber is a well known high level concept and that should be used to describe the function passed to `addEventListener`. It would be wrong to start name it by how it may be implemented because the implementation might differ between browsers. If you want to talk about specific implementations, we'd have to look at that specific implementation.

Comment: @Benia, why would you want to call anything but EventListener when all it does is to tell the browser "hey I have an attached event to me, when my element/object is clicked(or whatever..) do this thing " it doesn't loop nor listen to every events, the browser does that.. forEach() method is totally different thing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript `addEventListener` follows the famous "don't call us, we will call you." Also known as the Hollywood principle.

In software engineering it's also called the `observer` or `subscriber` part as in the publisher/observer design pattern.

Basically when you call addEventListener for let's say the click event with a callback. It's going to call the core of JavaScript engine saying

"Hey I have a function that wants to be called everytime there is a click."

The JavaScript engine is going to store a reference to the callback. And then during the JavaScript event loop, everytime there is a click event, it's simply going to call all its references to callback.

So the loop is indeed happening inside the JavaScript event loop (which you have little control over). But your callback is a simple function that subscribed to a specific event and will be called at the right time to react to this event. There is no magic behind it.

In fact, your callback is not really listening for event, it just subscribes itself once to a specific event and then it's done. It might be called in the future, but it's surely not actively listening for it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, in relation to the common JavaScript literature in 2017 (MDN), we shouldn't say it's a loop, because it's not one of the loops defined in JavaScript like `for` and `while`. We can indeed say it's an **observer** as it observers for each triggering of its associated event.

We don't iterate for each item in a collection, we observe for each triggering of the relevant event; One can say that the "for each" like behavior indicates "loopishness" and I personally find no flaw with that.

Comment: I  think the word you're looking for is 'iterator' :)

Comment: It's not an iterator. [An iterator describes a very specific kind of object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterator_protocol). Neither `addEventtListener` nor the callback passed to it implement this protocol.

Comment: @FelixKling I was talking about `forEach()` specifically, I probably should have clarified. Unless you're saying `forEach()` isn't an iterator?

Comment: @Beau: I didn't say that but it would be true. `forEach` is a normal function, not an iterator. As I said in my previous comment, an *iterator* is a very specific kind of object in JavaScript (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterator_protocol) though I can see how one could consider `forEach` to be an iterator in a more general sense (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator).

Comment: @FelixKling Let's call it an observable then! Oh wait…